# Get SVG child element width in scss

Tags: css, svg

Given HTML for SVG shapes:

```
<svg id="shapes"...
    <g id="myShape" class="myClass">
        <g>
            <path fill="#E9EEF1"...
```

And output CSS from SCSS:

```
svg g {
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

**How do I get the SVG child shape width (in pixels) into CSS?**

I'm able to get this with JavaScript:

```
var shape = document.getElementById('myShape');
console.log(shape.getBBox());
```

But need to rotate the SVG child shape using `transform-origin`. I was using `@include transform-origin(50%);`, but I cannot use 50% as Chrome and FireFox interpret % differently. So I need to get the width of the svg shape into CSS so I can transform it.

Comment: SCSS can't do anything that CSS alone cannot do.

Comment: You might be better of with something like [**Greensock.js**](https://greensock.com/) that will do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @Paulie_D this looks awesome! thanks for recommending. How do I use GSAP within scss though?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking...what do you need SCSS/CSS for?